# What's the chance of a lecturer in foreign country to obtain a teaching job in US community college?

Tags: teaching, community-college

I'm asking this question for my mom, who has been a college lecturer for 20+ years in communication study related field in non-English speaking country. She got her master degree in US back in 1990.

My parents received their green cards(US permanent resident) about 3 years ago and are debating between whether to completely stay in US (so they can satisfy the requirement of applying for citizenship as soon as possible) or to stay in US just enough to keep the permanent resident (so they can still work in the home country for a while).

The issue is, if both of them quit their jobs to completely settle in US. In the next few years the only income of the family will mostly** be my* TA-ship as a Ph.D. student (in math), which can hardly support the entire family.

Therefore, my mom contacted me and asked me this question recently. I have little idea about it, so I'm looking for help here.

Thanks for any suggestion in advance.

*I'm a US citizen who was born in the US.

**My dad can work online, but the income will drop significantly.

Answer (score 1):

The safe thing to do is to assume, for the time being, that their stay in the U.S. should be minimalist, and that they should hold onto their existing jobs in their home country.  However, your mother could certainly apply for some teaching positions in the U.S., and if the job search goes well, your parents could change plans at that point.  (However, even in that case, I would advise them not to burn their bridges right away.)

Community college jobs do not necessarily pay very well, and there is no guarantee of getting such a position, for anyone, at any given time in any given location.